# Deploy React Frontend, FastApi Backend with Docker-Compose on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, docker, heroku, docker-compose, fastapi

I want to deploy a worker (FastApi) and a web (react) container to Heroku using docker-compose. Running locally, everything works. But on Heroku, the frontend cannot reach the backend.

Dockerfile.worker

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.7

WORKDIR /app
COPY app .
COPY requirements.txt ./requirements.txt

ENV IS_IN_DOCKER=true

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r ./custom_model/custom_requirements.txt

CMD uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8800
```

Dockerfile.web

```
# pull official base image
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent

# add app
COPY . ./

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml (using the Port Env variable from heroku for the frontend, locally i have a .env File with PORT=80)

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  ml-starter-frontend:
    depends_on:
      - ml-starter-backend
    container_name: ml-starter-frontend
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.web
    ports:
      - '${PORT}:3000'
    restart: always
   ml-starter-backend:
     container_name: ml-starter-backend
     build:
       context: ./backend
       dockerfile: Dockerfile.worker
     restart: always
```

setupProxy.js in React src

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(
        '/api/*',
        createProxyMiddleware({
            target: 'http://ml-starter-backend:8800',
            changeOrigin: true,
        })
    );
};
```

Call in React frontend to backend

```
export const getConfiguration = () => async (dispatch) =>{

    const {data} = await axios.get('/api/configs')
    dispatch({type: GET_CONFIGURATION, payload: data })

}
```

Running locally the call works:
[Locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpF0f.png)

Deployment to heroku:

```
heroku container:push --recursive --app {appName}
heroku container:release worker --app {appName}
heroku container:release web --app {appName}
```

Frontend cannot reach backend:
[Heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6Gj9.png)

Heroku Worker (FastAPI) log

```
2021-04-09T10:10:55.322684+00:00 app[worker.1]: INFO:     Application startup complete.
2021-04-09T10:10:55.325926+00:00 app[worker.1]: INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8800 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Heroku Web (React) Log

```
2021-04-09T10:11:21.572639+00:00 app[web.1]: [HPM] Proxy created: /  -> http://ml-starter-backend:8800
```

.....

```
2021-04-09T10:25:37.404622+00:00 app[web.1]: [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/configs from {appName}.herokuapp.com to http://ml-starter-backend:8800 (ENOTFOUND) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

If possible i would like to avoid nginx as I already spent 2 hours trying to make it work with proxies in the prod build. Does anybody have experience with heroku and docker-compose and could give me a hint how to fix this?

Comment: Did you solve this? I am also looking at practice to see how to host react app and api in web and worker role and proxy worker via web

Comment: Hey Ramesh, FYI I answered my question..

Comment: Great. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

For everybody with a similiar problem.. Actually i ended up with a workaround.. I made a dockerfile containing the backend and frontend.. and deployed it to Heroku as a web app..

During my search i discovered, that Heroku workers are not really suitable in a HTTP scenario. If I understood it right, they are meant for reading messages from a queue.. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing

Answer (score 0):

Yup, I did something like what Loki34 did too. My approach was to run `npm run build`, then have FastAPI serve these build files. And like what Loki34 says, this is a workaround approach, meaning it's probably not the best approach out there when it comes to deploying frontend and backend in Docker containers. Anyway, those who are curious about how I did it can check out this app that I did: https://github.com/yxlee245/app-iris-ml-react-fastapi