Deploy FastAPI to Heroku with Docker Container Registry
The Problem
I am deploying a Docker image running FastAPI to Heroku using the Docker Container Registry deployment method. When I deploy the container I get the following logs when I run heroku logs --app <app-name> --tail
2024-06-03T20:57:32.222808+00:00 app[api]: Release v29 created by user dxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
2024-06-03T20:57:32.222808+00:00 app[api]: Deployed web (228f5e77d4e2) by user dxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
2024-06-03T20:57:45.637479+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `/bin/sh -c \"./start.sh\ \$\{PORT\}\"`
2024-06-03T20:57:46.235100+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2024-06-03T20:57:46.185240+00:00 app[web.1]: /bin/sh: 1: ./start.sh 53182: not found
2024-06-03T20:57:46.255899+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

In the Heroku UI I can see the command for starting a web process is web /bin/sh -c \"./start.sh\ \$\{PORT\}\" which is correct as that command works locally. I've even exec'd into the container and run /bin/sh -c "./start.sh <port>" to verify it will work, and it does (meaning I can hit any and all of my API endpoints and get the expected results).
The Details
Dockerfile
FROM node:21 as ui-build

ENV PORT $PORT

WORKDIR /opt/ui

COPY ui .
RUN npm ci && npm run build

FROM python:3.11 as final-build

WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY --from=ui-build /opt/ui/build ./ui/build
COPY server server

RUN cd server && pip install -r requirements.txt

# Apparently Heroku doesn't respect the EXPOSE directive.
EXPOSE $PORT

WORKDIR /opt/app/server
COPY ./start.sh .

# Not sure why these commands are not working but the start.sh script seems to be going in the right direction.
# ENTRYPOINT [ "uvicorn", "api.app:app" ]
# CMD [ "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", $PORT ]
CMD "./start.sh ${PORT}"

I'm using the gonuit/heroku-docker-deploy Github Action to build and push the docker image to Heroku's container registry. Here is how I use the action in my workflow.
name: Build and Push Image

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build-image:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Build and Push to Heroku
        uses: gonuit/heroku-docker-deploy@v1.3.3
        with:
          email: test@gmail.com
          heroku_api_key: ${{ secrets.HEROKU_API_KEY }}
          heroku_app_name: <app-name>


The Links
These are some of the links I've used to come up with code I currently have but neither has worked for me.

https://akshaykhatale.medium.com/deploy-fastapi-on-heroku-using-docker-container-a920f839de9b
How to deploy fast api as a backend in docker container to heroku

This final link is the official Heroku Docs on deploying w/ Docker Container Registry which to the best of my knowledge I've implemented identically.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime

The Solution
An ideal solution for me would be able to deploy my application using Docker, and Github Actions. If I need to add a Procfile or Heroku.yml file to the application I'm alright with that it just seems to be something that's not needed for the deployment method I'm using.

My answer is basically a re-skin of this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67747986/1464160
The correct way to define the CMD directive is
CMD [ "sh", "-c", "uvicorn api.app:app --host=0.0.0.0 --port=${PORT:-8000}" ]

Of course the path api.app:app and the default port # can be changed to whatever you want it to be. The important part seems to be having "sh", "-c" at the beginning of the CMD directive.

Perhaps try changing CMD to:
CMD ["/path/to/start.sh", "--port ${PORT}"]

Thanks or the suggestion, but I'm getting not the same error but basically the same error.
2024-06-05T14:26:25.259174+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `/bin/sh -c \[\ \"/opt/app/server/start.sh\",\ \ \37593\ \]`
2024-06-05T14:26:25.883545+00:00 app[web.1]: /bin/sh: 1: [: /opt/app/server/start.sh,: unexpected operator
2024-06-05T14:26:25.951508+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 2

This suggestion while a Docker best practice is essentially the same thing I have in the original post.
